# Shoes tooltips?

Tags: ruby, tooltip, shoes

I'm using the [shoes GUI toolkit](http://shoesrb.com), and I'd like to have a tooltip show up when the user rolls over a button.

Is there a way to do that in Shoes? Or do I need to file a bug/feature request in Shoes itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at this part of shoes-contrib: https://github.com/shoes/shoes-contrib/blob/master/events/background-hover.rb

Answer (score 2):

Here a solution for red shoes

```
Shoes.app do
  s = stack :width => 400, :height => 400 do
    @tip = flow :height => 20 do
      para "" 
    end
    @r = flow  :width => 60, :height => 20 do
      background red
      para "button"
      click do
        alert("You clicked me !!")
      end
      hover do
        @tip.clear()
        @tip.para "this is the tip"
      end
      leave do
        @tip.clear(background white)
        @tip.para ""
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: Verified with Shoes walkabout (Revision 2333).

Answer (score 1):

in windows that won't work with red shoes since alle events are stealed by windows.
You can get this to work if you don't use a native controll, eg a shape instead of a button.
You could also use green shoes instead of red shoes.
Cheers